# Prevent Onload Infinite Looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, razor

i have a Question . . How can i Prevent this to infinite loop because im new to Google maps and Jquery.

Ive read alot of Answers but not even one is working

This is my Codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder, infoBubble;
    var map;
    //var mgr;

    function initialize() {
        var minZoomLevel = 4;
        var zooms = 7;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: minZoomLevel,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Bounds for North America
        var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

        // Listen for the dragend event
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
            if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

            // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

            var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (x < minX) x = minX;
            if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
            if (y < minY) y = minY;
            if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
        });


        // Limit the zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
        });
        codeAddress();
    }

    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    function codeAddress() {
        infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            map: map,
            shadowStyle: 0,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 10,
            arrowSize: 15,
            maxWidth: 300,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#ccc',
            arrowPosition: 50,
            arrowStyle: 0
        });
        $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList', function (address) {
            $.each(address, function () {
                var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
                var Name = this["Name"];
                var Gender = this["Gender"];
                var Bdate = this["Birthdate"];
                var ID = this["Worker_ID"];
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal
                        })

                        var link = $('<a href="#">' + currVal + '</a>')
                         .data('location', results[0].geometry.location);
                        $('#places').append($('<li>').append(link));
                        link.on('click', function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            google.maps.event.trigger(address[0], "click");
                            infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                            infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Worker/WorkerDetails?workerId=' + ID + '">View Profile</a></center>');
                            infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                        }
);

                        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
                            $('#places li a').css('display', function () {
                                return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))
                      ? ''
                      : 'none';
                            });
                        });



                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                                infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Worker/WorkerDetails?workerId=' + ID + '">View Profile</a></center>');
                                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));
                        address.push(marker);

                    }
                    else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                        setTimeout(codeAddress, 2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });
            });
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'bounds_changed');
        });
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
    }

</script>
```

I think this is what is causing the items to loop

```
` window.onload = function () {
            initialize();
        }`
```

and this

```
` google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
            });
            codeAddress();    <------- This one`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call of initialize isn't the reason for a infinite loop, initialize will be called 1 time.

The only reason I see for a infinite loop is codeAddress:

```
 else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    setTimeout(codeAddress, 2000);
                }
```

when this condition is true, you call codeAddress again what makes no difference, you will get the same result again and again(with a delay of 2 seconds).

**You may either:**

1. let `/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList` return only up to 10 addresses
2. ommit in the return of `/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList` the addresses that already have been returned in previous requests

**or:**

Use a increasing timeout for each call of `geocoder.geocode` (increase it by 150ms)

Comment: Dr.Molle is right: with 2 entries in json file I got results without any problems. Increasing it to 12 I got `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error.

Comment: sir. actually the possible number of markers that will be shown is approximately 10000 addresses . . how could i handle it because it makes my map crash. .. another sir . .how should i Ommit the return of LoadWorkerList

Comment: sir i have a question. . Why my Controller already been accessed by the JsonResult even i am only on logon screen??